# How to show animal lineage/pedigree in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I need to show the pedigree or lineage of an animal in my wordpress site.

Currently I have the animals set up as custom post types, with data inserted using the amazing Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

I can't really find any good plugins for this that do it well, especially those that can output standards compliant HTML and usable CSS without tables.

Even if it's a list item, that's cool, I can work out the CSS.

But what would be the best way of inputting an animal's lineage / pedigree, up to 4 levels deep (eg: 1)Parents 2)Grand parents 3)Great Grand Parents 4) Great Great Grand parents

Really appreciate your help on this one!

Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animalia_%28disambiguation%29)

> **Animalia** is the *taxonomic* kingdom comprising all animals (including human beings).

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

> **Taxonomy** is one of those words that most people never hear or use. Basically, a taxonomy is a way to group things together.
>
> For example, I might have a bunch of different types of animals. I can group them together according to various characteristics and then assign those groups names. This is something most people encounter in biology classes, and it is known as the [Linnaean Taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnaean_taxonomy).
>
> In WordPress, a "taxonomy" is a grouping mechanism for some posts (or links or custom post types).

Just use [Categories](http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/categories-vs-tags/) -a type of taxonomy- to group and categorize them.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've set up a bunch of Custom Taxonomies (Father, Fathers Father etc), and I enter these in on the custom post template.  Cheers!